# Options for RAID recovery after motherboard dies

Tags: motherboard, raid, recovery

## The Skinny

Personal home computer with RAID built with the onboard Intel chipset hardware RAID controller has died after a power fluctuation.  The system hardware was kind of old.  Will the RAID array be usable via a different (much newer) Intel onboard RAID controller?

## The Explanation

We have a 12 TB (4x 4TB HDDs in RAID 5) that was running off of an [ASUS Z87I-Deluxe](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16813132028) motherboard using the onboard RAID functionality of the chipset.  This board is from 2014.  The system was plugged into a UPS, but after a power fluctuation we turned the system off (just in case) and after attempting to reboot, it would only power for <1 second.  Removed/disconnected RAM, GPU, all peripherals and drives, and plugged in a different PSU.  No dice.  Motherboard is about the only thing left.

I have a [GIGABYTE Z390 AORUS PRO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HRZRBRJ) and I understand I can run a RAID from that chipset as well.  I am hoping to buy a 16TB HDD and get the RAID up and running and make a backup.  I just need the RAID up long enough for the backup to do, and then I may swear off of RAID.

## The Question

Can my RAID (Intel Rapid Storage) be picked up by a newer generation Intel RAID controller?  Are there going to be any ramifications to that?  The drives were still solid according to a SMART dump from about 30 minutes before we powered it down so they are likely not an issue at least for now.

Comment: Linux `mdadm` should support it even on AMD boards if you set `IMSM_NO_PLATFORM=1`. Please make backups in the future, RAID is nice for single drive failures but does not replace backups.

Comment: @frostschutz Yeah, haven't really had money for a large enough backup media for a while.  Cobbled this RAID together with spare hardware and some donated drives from a friend.  Believe me I wanted to.  I'd love to have a cloud backup solution as well.  One of these days when there are no other things to point my money toward (that are more pressing) maybe I'll be able to.